# pngwritec error in Matlab 2017b

Tags: matlab, image-processing, png

The pngwritec function is at the core of my program, but however, I get a series of errors when I run my main file.

```
Error using pngwritec
PNG library failed: Write Error.
```

There does not seem to be any documentation available online, yet somehow, when I ran the same program a couple of days ago, there was no issue. Is this a side effect of some new Matlab update? I'm using Matlab 2017b.

Edit: 
The error shows up at the first time I need to convert an image to PNG using imwrite.

```
        if (~exist(fullfile(denoiseFolder, [nameF '_d' extF]), 'file') | overwrite)
            if saveWaveletCoeffs
                waveletFileName = fullfile(saveWaveletFolder, [nameF '_w.mat']);
            else
                waveletFileName = '';
            end
            imIn = imread(fileName);
            imOut = waveletDenoise(imIn, sigma0, waveletFileName);
            imOut = uint8(round(imOut));
            fileName = fullfile(denoiseFolder, [nameF '_d' extF]);
            imwrite(imOut, fileName, 'png');   %Error here
        end
```

Comment: How do you expect anybody to spot the error in your program if you don't show your code? Type `dbstop if error` at the MATLAB command prompt and run your code again. Now you can examine the code at the point of failure. This is the way that you can figure out what is wrong.

Comment: Yes, I tried that out. It turns out that the code stops at the 'writing function' method in the imwrite.m file. It doesn't look like the conversion to PNG is happening.